# Pass third parameter to ajax

Tags: php, ajax

everyone.
I have such code:

```php
require_once('class_mysql.php');
$mysql=new class_mysql();

$query="SELECT rate,count(id) as cnt FROM pubgraph.votes WHERE vote=1 GROUP BY rate;";
$result=$mysql->querySelect($query,'rate');

$date_query = "SELECT max(dt), '1' as v_virtual from pubgraph.votes";
$date_result = $mysql->querySelect($date_query,'v_virtual');


$res=$result[$_GET['vote']]['cnt']?$result[$_GET['vote']]['cnt']:0;


print $res;
```

Can you explane to me this string please?

```php
 $res=$result[$_GET['vote']]['cnt']?$result[$_GET['vote']]['cnt']:0;
```

What i need is to pass $date_result to this string.  Thanks.

This is my javasript code:
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
    getyes();
    function getyes() {
        $("#yescnt").load("ajax_vote.php?vote=1");
        $("#nocnt").load("ajax_vote.php?vote=2");
        $("#date").load("ajax_vote.php?date=1");
        t=setTimeout(function() { getyes(); },5000);
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you explain your exact problem in detail?

Comment: Yes. What i need is to pass the result of the second query to javascript file(#date value). I know, how to pass 2 parameters of $query to my js and it works. But when I try to pass third parameter      $("#date").load("ajax_vote.php?date=1"); it prints only zero.

Comment: You have to use isset() function and evaluate the query string having data or not and echo the result respectively

Comment: Probably [@Ram Sharma] answer is resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

it's just if else conditions. in other way you can write this like

```
if($result[$_GET['vote']]['cnt']){
   $res = $result[$_GET['vote']]['cnt'];
}else{
   $res = 0;
}
```

if you want to assign $date_result to this variable than you can use the above condition and assign value accordingly.

I feel in your case you have to add if else conditions in your code like

```
  <?php
  require_once('class_mysql.php');
  $mysql=new class_mysql();
  $res = '';
  if(isset($_GET['date'])){
    $date_query = "SELECT max(dt) as mxdate, '1' as v_virtual from pubgraph.votes";
    $result = $mysql->querySelect($date_query,'v_virtual');
    $res=$result[$_GET['date']]['mxdate']?$result[$_GET['date']]['mxdate']:0;
    print $res;  
  }else{
    $query="SELECT rate,count(id) as cnt FROM pubgraph.votes WHERE vote=1 GROUP BY rate;";
    $result=$mysql->querySelect($query,'rate');
    $res=$result[$_GET['vote']]['cnt']?$result[$_GET['vote']]['cnt']:0;
    print $res;
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks! But how I should pass my $date_result there? I load this values by javascript:        $("#yescnt").load("ajax_vote.php?vote=1");
        $("#nocnt").load("ajax_vote.php?vote=2");
        $("#date").load("ajax_vote.php?date=1");

Comment: wait, for moment please.

Comment: I have edit my answer look into that and check your date query that it return you date properly

Comment: I have earlier explain that please check date query properly

Comment: Yes, I changed my query like that$date_query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(max(dt), '%d %b %Y %T') AS mxdate, '1' as v_virtual from pubgraph.votes";                                                                    but it didnt make any effect. Second query result doesnt work too.

Comment: ahhh, I missed last curly brace after else statement. Now it works, but output repeated values. Two simular dates instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a ternary condition.
Have a look here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

this sintax is called [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), is a short if/else

```
 $res=$result[$_GET['vote']]['cnt']?$result[$_GET['vote']]['cnt']:0;
```